# Как создать библиотеки с moc файлами?

Tags: qt5, cmake

Есть 2 библиотеки Foo и Foo2, совершенно одинаковые, только названия разные.  Вот такого вида:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void Signals();

public slots:
    void Slot() {}
};

#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(FooLib)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(LIB_HEADERS Foo.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_HEADERS})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES 
                    WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON
)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
```

И исполняемый файл:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    Foo2 f2;

    QObject::connect(&f2, &Foo2::Signal, &f, &Foo::Slot);
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Test)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(HEADERS StdAfx.h)
set(SOURCES main.cpp  StdAfx.cpp)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo2)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo2)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE FooLib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Foo2Lib)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/YuStdAfx.h")
set_source_files_properties(StdAfx.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/YcStdAfx.h")


add_definitions(/FI"StdAfx.h")
```

В итоге вот такая ошибка:

```
3>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Foo2::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Foo2@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

Answer (score -1):

Серьезно, библиотека из одного хидера... Во-первых, чтобы компилятор вам что-то скомпилировал, у вас должны быть `cpp` файлы. Во-вторых, раз вы используете `qt` вы должны включить `MOC` для файлов, где используется `Q_OBJECT`. Делается это так:

`set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`

Comment: Может кто-нибудь пояснит за что минус?